# Append elements with childs and classes using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, element

I'm trying to create a grid table using jQuery.
So instend of adding those elements into html page:

```
<div id="grid" class="gridTable">
    <div class="row">
        <span class="cell head"></span>
        <span class="cell head"></span>
        <span class="cell head"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span class="cell"></span>
        <span class="cell"></span>
        <span class="cell"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span class="cell"></span>
        <span class="cell"></span>
        <span class="cell"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span class="cell"></span>
        <span class="cell"></span>
        <span class="cell"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to add only the grid container:

```
<div id="grid" class="gridTable"><div>
```

and inside of this container to add my rows dynamically using jQuery `append()` or other method:

```
<div class="row">
    <span class="cell head"></span>
    <span class="cell head"></span>
    <span class="cell head"></span>
</div>
```

repeating each time I want. I have tried something like:

```
$('.gridTable').append( $("<div></div>").addClass('row') );
```

but I don't know how to add `.cell` child of appended elements.

See full html code in **[fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/o04btr3j/289/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store appended element in variable and use it after append. To do this work, you need to write new element in selector and use [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) to appending element.

```js
var row = $('<div></div>').addClass("row").appendTo(".gridTable");
row.append("<span class='cell head'>col</span");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid" class="gridTable"></div>
```

If you want to create all row and column of table dynamicaly, see bottom code.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    var row = $('<div></div>').addClass("row").appendTo(".gridTable");
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        if (i == 0)
         row.append("<span class='cell head'>head</span");
        else
            row.append("<span class='cell'>col</span");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid" class="gridTable"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a function that returns a row object with specified number of cells and call it for each row:

**TIP:**

Adjust the function as you like (e.g. It can take a parameter for cell classes)

```js
var grid = $('#grid');

/**
*   Returns a jQuery object of a row
*   param cells {number} The number of cells
*/
function getRow(cells, customClass) {  
  var c = '';      
  for (var i=0;i<cells;i++) {          
      c += '<span class="cell ' + customClass + '">Cell</span>';
  }
  var row = $('<div class="row">' + c + '</div>');  
  return row;  
}

// Add 5 rows
var rows = 5;
for (var r=1;r<=rows;r++) {
  var customClass = (r == 1) ? 'head' : '';
  grid.append(getRow(3, customClass));
}
```

```css
.cell { 
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px 10px;
  border:1px solid #d8d8d8;
}
.head { font-weight:bold }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid" class="gridTable"></div>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! Just one more thing, for first <row>  I want to add two classes on <span> .cell and .head